# Powershell Nested functions error handling failing

Tags: powershell

I need help on the issue which I'm facing using the below code.

The below function has 2 nested functions, the problem here is when I get an error in the first nested function I put a break to come out entirely from the Main function (without executing anything further).
In my case, it is continuing to execute the 2nd nested function, which I
don't want.
<
Write-host "All the retry are finished..!"
break >

Hereafter break, I would want it to come out from the main function, need your help to correct me if I am
phrasing them in the wrong way..!

```
Function MAIN
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (     
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)] [string]$server 
        )          
    Function Failover-Readiness
    {  
        Try
        {
            [int]$Log_size_th=100
            [int]$retry=0
 
            $TF=
            "sample query 1"
            DO
           { 
                $RS=invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database Master -Query $TF | Where-Object{$_.role_desc -like "*secondary*"} |
                    `Where-Object {($_.log_send_queue_size -gt $Log_size_th) -or ($_.redo_queue_size -gt $Log_size_th)}
 
                ##############################################
                $Q= "sample query 2"
                $R=(Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database "MASTER" -Query $Q -QueryTimeout 20 -ea stop ).cnt
                $Count =$R
                $RSCOUNT=$RS.count
                write-host `n"open tran count is $count and log/redo queue size DB count is $RSCOUNT " -ForegroundColor Yellow
                
                if (($count -gt 0) -or ($RS.Count -ge 1))
                {
                    $retry=$retry+1
                    write-host "retry count is  $retry"
                    Write-Warning "there are atleast 1 open tran or Log/redo queue size are gt 100"  
                    start-sleep -Seconds 5
                    
                    if ($retry -gt 5)
 
                    {
                        Write-host "All the retry are finihsed..!" -ForegroundColor Red             
                        break
                    } 
                }
                else
                {
                    write-host `n"There are no open transactions and Log/redo queue size is lt 100 !" -ForegroundColor green
                }
            }
            while(($count -gt 0) -or ($RS.Count -gt 1) )
        } ##Try
        catch
        {
           write-host $_.exception.message -ForegroundColor Red
        }
 
    }##Function

Failover-Readiness

    Function Test
    {
        write-host "Test Function"
    }
Test
}
```

Comment: Use `throw` instead of `Write-Error` or `Write-Host` if you want the errors to quit and bubble up the exceptions to the calling script

Comment: would you please add meaningful indentation and remove the meaningless extra blank lines? right now, you code is needlessly difficult to read. you can fix most of that by loading your code into VSCode and using the `format document` command. [*grin*]

Comment: @Theo: I tried using throw but it's not coming out of the main function, it helps to come out of the function where it hits the error, here if I see any error  don't want to it should come out of from man function without executing further,